# how to create unique reference number - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Suppliers which have their own products. WP backend is almost redesigned and there I have a page(with form) where 'admin' can add new supplier and I need to create unique a reference number for each supplier when form will be submitted.

***Plus, I have a "Sort by" dropdown and one of the sorting options is by "Reference number".***

At first, I thought to use the POST ID as reference number, but don't think that this can be best solution, as POST IDs will be different when some posts will be removed. Also I was thinking to use `uniqid()` function with some digit limit and only digits.

What is best to reach this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a new custom meta field for (i.e. `supplier_id`) and create a function which ensure that this `supplier_id` is unique. This function will be executed every time when a supplier form submitted.

The action hook [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) is triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated. So we can use it for this purpose.

**From the documentation:**

> save_post is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email. The data for the post is stored in $_POST, $_GET or the global $post_data, depending on how the post was edited. For example, quick edits use $_POST.
>
> Since this action is triggered right after the post has been saved, you can easily access this post object by using get_post($post_id)

**Example:**

```
function save_supplier_id( $post_id, $post, $update ) { 

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);       
    if ( "supplier" != $post_type ) return;    

    if ( isset( $_POST['supplier_id'] ) ) {
        
        $my_supplier_id = $_POST['supplier_id'];
        
        if ( ! is_int( $my_supplier_id ) ) $my_supplier_id = 1;
        
        $all_other_suppliers = get_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,           
            'post_type'        => 'supplier',
            'post__not_in'     => array( $post_id )         
        ));
        
        $all_other_ids = array_map( function( $supplier ) { return $supplier->ID; }, all_other_suppliers );
        
        if ( count( $all_other_ids ) && in_array( $my_supplier_id, $all_other_ids ) ) {
            // ID is already in use by another supplier, let's create an new one
            $my_supplier_id = max( $all_other_ids ) + 1;
        }
        
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'supplier_id', $my_supplier_id ) );
    }       
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_supplier_id', 10, 3 );
```

**Explantion:**
The format for `supplier_id`is simple a consecutive number. If the provided id is not an integer, we set it to 1. Now we get all other supplier id's and check if the give id no occur twice. If so, the we get the max id and increase it by 1.

Comment: and generate number with uniqid()? @Andy Tschiersch

Comment: IMO a three-digit consecutive number should be enough.

Comment: do you have some example on how to do this? @Andy Tschiersch

Comment: I have expanded my answer to an example.